# Creating PDF File in Windows 8 Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am creating a Windows 8 app which will need to export some content from a RichTextEditor to a PDF file.

Can anyone advise the best way of doing this and if there are any Free tools available

thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other option ITextSharp http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

you need import the library that suport RTF or HTML

Comment: ITextSharp can't be used with windows 8 apps

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), there are lots of examples provided in many languages (including C#).